# rails blob path vs service url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a rails application that has Active Storage and stores objects in Amazon S3.

So far, I have been using `rails_blob_path` but then I discovered `service_url`.

`rails_blob_path` returns an URL to the rails application and rails redirects you to S3.

`service_url` directly returns the URL to the S3 object.

I wonder what could be the advantage(s) of using one or the other? When is it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation on `service_url` here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html#method-i-service_url

Basically, there's usually not a good reason to provide your users with the `service_url`.